# What do these Boot Loader Settings do in the OpenSUSE installer?

Tags: grub2, opensuse, boot-loader

I'm looking for a short explanation of each highlighted setting in the screenshot, and which other setting it should/shouldn't be used with (if applicable).

[image]

[image]

These are my specific concerns:

- What happens if I check both `Boot from Root Partition` and `Boot from Master Boot Record`, do I end up with two slightly different OpenSUSE entries in the MBR?
- What if I don't check `Set active Flag for Boot Partition`? Since it's specifically for Boot Partition, should I still set the active flag if I **only** check `Boot from MBR` above?
- What is `Write generic Boot Code to MBR`? What happens if I leave it checked and also check `Boot from MBR` above, will one overwrite the other?
- What menu does `Hide Menu on Boot` hide, is it the Grub selection menu in the MBR? If I need the menu, how do I bring it up again?
- When using `Protect Boot Loader with Password`, what happens if a Windows installer tries to overwrite it? Will the Windows installation fail? Do I have to enter the password even when reinstalling OpenSUSE?

Comment: does this answer your question https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book.opensuse.reference/cha.grub2.html#sec.grub2.yast2.config?

Comment: do not touch those, leave everything as standard ESPECIALLY for dual boot systems. otherwise the loader will be put where it can't be reached.